# Exclusive OR a set with itself

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Given set A is a finite set, then $ A\oplus A=\emptyset $ and $A\oplus \emptyset = A$.

These make perfect sense to me, since the XOR operator requires only one "True" Condition for the output to be true, i.e. $A\oplus A$ will always be false since they have the same truth value.

Is there a different or more formal way to prove this?

Comment: How do you define $A \oplus B$ for sets?

Comment: $A\oplus B $ results in a set with elements from just A or just B. Say, $A={1,2,3,4} $ and $B={3,4,5,6}$, then $A\oplus B = {3,4} $. At least I think that's correct.

Comment: XOR is the same as symmetric difference.  The symmetric difference of two sets is the set of elements in one but not both.  So clearly, the symmetric difference of a set with itself is empty since every element is in "both" sets.

Comment: You were asked how you *define* $A\oplus B$. You gave an example. "Formal proofs" start with formal definitions. Given two sets, how do you define $A\oplus B$? If you cannot give a proper definition, it's impossible to give a proper proof of the statement.

Comment: @Jabernet Your example cannot possibly be correct, if $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $B = \{3,4,5,6\}$ then the set $\{3,4\}$ represents the intersection of the two sets: $A \cap B$.  The way I understand your question/the exclusive or is that the $A \oplus B$ would be the set $\{1,2,6\}$ (i.e. the elements that are in one of $A$ or $B$ but _not_ the other).

Comment: Right, I had that backwards and forgot to edit it. It should be {1,2,5,6}

Answer (score 3):

I would assume a formal definition would be something of the form:

$$
A \oplus B  \equiv (A \cup B) \backslash (A\cap B)
$$

In this way,

$$
A \oplus A = (A \cup A) \backslash (A \cap A) = A \backslash A = \emptyset
$$

Comment: I was thinking along these lines.